# Elegantly adding basic pages as sub-pages in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I have a main page (let's call it "GROUP") accessible from a site-wide navigation bar. I've created other sub-pages ("SUB1" through "SUBn") and set their `Parent item` to "GROUP" in the `Edit Basic page` panel, but am at a loss as to how I can get each such SUBn to show up on the GROUP page.

I could simply create a `<ul>` of permalinks to the SUBn's, but that seems a bit inelegant and inflexible. Is there a native Drupal way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add GROUP to a menu (usually Primary Links for a small site), then add SUB1...SUBn as subpages on the menu, so you have an arrangement like:

- Home
- GROUP
- - SUB1
- - ...
- - SUBn
- Contact Us
- Etc

Then use Menu Block from http://drupal.org/project/menu_block to create a block that shows entries at the first level and have the block show up on the pages where you want the subpage list to appear.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Bones](http://drupal.org/project/bones) module to automate the node/menu structure creation.